# Getting a value when showBottomSheet closes

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I send the value when a `showBottomSheet` closed?

```
    var sheetController = showBottomSheet(
        context: context, builder: (context) => BottomSheet(
             onClosing:(){},
             builder: (BuildContext context) {
               return Container(
                      width:100.0,
                     child:FlatButton(
                            onPressed:(){
                             Navigator.pop(context,data);
                       }))
}));
        sheetController.closed.then((value) async {
         print(value);
      }
    });
```

i want to get data but it prints `null`

Comment: This happens because of a bug in Flutter  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66837

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to this :

```
var sheetController = showBottomSheet(
context: context, builder: (context) => displayBottomSheet(number));
sheetController.closed.then((value) async {
      await print(value);
}
```

Comment: the number is for controlling which bottomsheet to show. i want to get a value when that bottomsheet closes i read somewhere to send data with Navigator.pop but its not working

Comment: you can use result argument to return the result. look at this : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html

Comment: i did use the result argument but still prints null. its not receiving the result

Comment: you forgot to write await keyword as you are assigning value to number in async. edited the code. check it out.

Comment: i edited the question i think 'number' confused u a bit.

Comment: Try await print and let me know the result.

Comment: this is pretty much what i ended up with but i dont get the value it just prints null